# Crystal Report Viewer File format in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using VS 2008, ASP.NET 3.5 and Crystal Report 10.5.

I am unable to see a Microsoft Word - Editable (RTF) File format in my viewer export drop downlist.

How can I add Microsoft Word - Editable (RTF) into my File format dropdown list.

Please help me out!!

Thanks!

Comment: RTF is for Wordpad i think, for MS-word is doc(before office 2007) or docx (office 2007 and later)

Comment: Actually I want to export CR into Word Document but When I export all frames show into word document and I want to remove those frames so, I went couple of forums and they mention use a Microsoft Word - Editable (RTF)  instead of Microsoft Word

Answer (score 0):

I think you need crystal report XI (ie 11), this is the first version to support .rpt.

If you look into following directory on your web server: 
*aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4\JS*

or full path for most web servers

*C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4\js*

Open up the export.js file look for the following code if you see it then it should be able to export to rtf and/or you need to make sure you have the **Crxf_rtf.dll** which enabled exporting to rtf. See this doc for more detail [Exporting Changes in Crystal Reports from 8.5 to XI](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/b052663a-8b1e-2b10-57b1-eb649a9f592a?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true).

```
if( rpt )
        {
            list += "<OPTION value=\"CrystalReports\">" + L_CrystalRptFormat + "</OPTION>";
        }
        if( pdf )
        {
            list += "<OPTION value=\"PDF\">" + L_AcrobatFormat + "</OPTION>";
        }
        if( word )
        {
            list += "<OPTION value=\"MSWord\">" + L_WordFormat + "</OPTION>";
        }
        if( xls )
        {
            list += "<OPTION value=\"MSExcel\">" + L_ExcelFormat + "</OPTION>";
        }
        if( recXls )
        {
            list += "<OPTION value=\"RecordToMSExcel\">" + L_ExcelRecordFormat + "</OPTION>";
        }
        if( rtf )
        {
            list += "<OPTION value=\"RTF\">" + L_RTFFormat +"</OPTION>";
        }
```